# Type '<Module>' from assembly ... contains more methods than the current implementation allows

Tags: c++, .net, clr

I'm trying to compile a relatively big legacy c++ project in visual-studio-2013 using /clr flag. The project generates a dll.

I get the following run-time exception:

`Type '<Module>' from assembly ... contains more methods than the current implementation allows`

I must add that this happens in Debug configuration only (Release - works). Also, the project heavily uses templates and macros, which (I suppose) contribute to the large amount of generated methods...

There is little to no documentation regarding this problem.
What I know from searching the net (don't know if it's accurate) is:

There is a limit of ~65K methods in a clr dll. All methods of all native classes go into some special `<Module>`, so it poses a global limit.

One suggestion was to split the project, but that's not very trivial, due to inter-class-dependencies. I suppose this is doable...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if it is a native C++ project, you can not convert it to a managed C++ project with the clr option

Comment: The problem is that you can.  This is a problem caused by the crude sledgehammer approach to making C++ usable from a .NET program.  Fall in the pit of success by segregating your legacy C++ code properly.  Compile it into a static library *without* /clr, link it to your C++/CLI project that just contains the ref class wrappers.

Comment: Several reasons why I think I can't go with your suggestion. First, I need to run code-coverage, and it might not work (not sure). Second, the library is written in a way that uses dllexport/dllimport conventions, so I would need to change it (although there is a macro, so It might not be expensive). Third, and I think most important - many of the functions are implemented in the header files of the library, hence some of the code would be compiled with /clr, while the rest would be compiled without it. I already saw bugs that looked like woodoo becuase of that. btw - tried Gf flag - no help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up separating code into two dlls, and removing some code that I wasn't using. The hard part was identifying "dead" code and making sure it's using templates extensively (otherwise I was just removing drops in a bucket).

I know it's not a solution you want to hear, but I couldn't find any other working workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this issue for a few weeks with VS2015.  In the end I found the linker option :`/OPT:REF` which can be found under `Project properties->Linker->Optomization->References`.  This removed about 12MB from the size of the output DLL and the exception is no longer thrown at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try enabling the use of Precompiled Headers for your C++/CLI project.

After disabling the use of Precompiled Headers, I hit this limit/error in a Debug build.  Then had to use the `/OPT:REF` trick provided by Scott's answer.  Kudos to that.  But it seems using Precompiled Headers can also reduce the total methods.

Comment: Perhaps Precompiled Headers use avoids duplicating methods among translation units, not exactly certain?